# How to run a Java program from an Unix script?

Tags: scripting, java, launcher

I try to compile a Java project from a Linux script, `run_nmc_engine.sh`. The problem is that I get an error when launching it :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class caos.aaai.CaosNMCEngine
```

The command I launched in my script was, more or less,

```
java -Xmx${MAXMEM} -cp .:${TOP}/build:${JCHEM}/lib/jchem.jar caos.aaai.CaosNMCEngine blablabla ...
```

I didn't add it all because I thought the error was in related to the first part of the command. I don't know where `JCHEM` is but I know it is

> *An implementation for chemical representation, search, storage, structural and non-structural data management functions.* from [ChemAxon website](https://chemaxon.com/products/jchem-engines)

It seems it can't find where the CaosNMCEngine.java file is. Yet, I thought it was well placed in the folder :

[image]

You can find the whole project on [the webpage of the project on GitHub](https://github.com/antoinecomp/MedicineConstruction). Let me know if you need anything more to complete the readme. Maybe you will have more luck comparing the script with the one from [the original project](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~aheifets/ChemicalPlanning/).

The full script is :

```
JCHEM=/Applications/ChemAxon/JChem-5.7.0
MAXMEM="2G"
if [[ `uname -a | grep Linux` ]] ;
then
JCHEM=/gpfs/home/aheifets/opt/jchem-5.7.1
MAXMEM="8G"
fi

TOP=`cd $(dirname $0)/../..; pwd -P`
PATH=$PATH:${JCHEM}/bin

# rm ReactorDemo.class
# javac -cp .:/Applications/ChemAxon/JChem-5.7.0/lib/jchem.jar -Xlint:unchecked ReactorDemo.java
# java -cp .:/Applications/ChemAxon/JChem-5.7.0/lib/jchem.jar ReactorDemo $1 $2 $3 #| tee /dev/stderr | mview - &

#rm RetroTests.class
#javac -cp .:/Applications/ChemAxon/JChem-5.7.0/lib/jchem.jar -Xlint:unchecked RetroTests.java
#java -cp .:/Applications/ChemAxon/JChem-5.7.0/lib/jchem.jar RetroTests $1 $2 $3 #| tee /dev/stderr | mview - &

date
#java -Xmx2G -cp .:${TOP}/build:${JCHEM}/lib/jchem.jar caos.aaai.CaosEngine ${TOP}/data/cleaned_reaction_library_JChem_5.7.0_DISABLED  ${TOP}/data/SML ${TOP}/data/33.smiles 8000 0 ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalRXNs ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalSML

#java -Xmx2G -cp .:${TOP}/build:${JCHEM}/lib/jchem.jar caos.aaai.CaosEngine ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/3/RXNs  ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/3/SML ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/3/goal_d3.smarts 1 0 ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalRXNs ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalSML

#PROBLEM=16
# for PROBLEM in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 18.1 19 20
#for PROBLEM in 11  #8 10 11 12 #1 12 14 15 16 #15 #11 12 14 16 18 19 8 9
for PROBLEM in 2
do
OUTDIR=rxndebug #exhaust #
mkdir -p ${TOP}/out/${OUTDIR}/${PROBLEM}
LOG=${TOP}/out/${OUTDIR}/${PROBLEM}/log
ERR=${TOP}/out/${OUTDIR}/${PROBLEM}/err

echo "==================================PROBLEM ${PROBLEM}=================================="
echo "==================================PROBLEM ${PROBLEM}==================================" > ${LOG}
echo "==================================PROBLEM ${PROBLEM}==================================" > ${ERR}
date
date > ${ERR}
#java -Xmx${MAXMEM} -cp .:${TOP}/build:${JCHEM}/lib/jchem.jar test.ReactorDemo2 $*
#java -Xmx${MAXMEM} -cp .:${TOP}/build:${JCHEM}/lib/jchem.jar caos.aaai.OperatorLibrary

#java -Xmx${MAXMEM} -cp .:${TOP}/build:${JCHEM}/lib/jchem.jar caos.aaai.CaosEngine ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/RXNs  ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/SML ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/goal.smiles 10000 0 ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalRXNs_DISABLED ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalSML >${LOG} 2>${ERR}

java -Xmx${MAXMEM} -cp .:${TOP}/build:${JCHEM}/lib/jchem.jar caos.aaai.CaosNMCEngine ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/RXNs_DISABLED  ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/SML ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/goal.smiles 10000 0 ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalRXNs ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalSML >${LOG} 2>${ERR}

#java -Xmx${MAXMEM} -cp .:${TOP}/build:${JCHEM}/lib/jchem.jar caos.aaai.CaosEngine ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/RXNs  ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/SML ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/goal.smiles 5 0 ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalRXNs ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalSML EXHAUSTIVE >${LOG} 2>>${ERR}

#java -Xmx${MAXMEM} -cp .:${TOP}/build:${JCHEM}/lib/jchem.jar caos.aaai.CaosEngine ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/RXNs  ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/SML ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/subgoals/goal_c.smiles 100 0 ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalRXNs ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalSML
#java -Xmx${MAXMEM} -cp .:${TOP}/build:${JCHEM}/lib/jchem.jar caos.aaai.CaosEngine ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/RXNs  ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/SML ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/subgoals/solution_B.smiles 100 0 ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalRXNs ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/GlobalSML
diff -b $LOG ${TOP}/data/BENCHMARK/PROBLEMS/${PROBLEM}/SOLUTION.txt

date
date >> ${ERR}
echo ${LOG}
done
```

Comment: You may be better off asking on Stack Overflow under `Java` tag, as this is rather a niche Java question than a Linux specific question.

Answer (score 1):

1) `java` is really looking for a `.class` at that point, not a `.java`.

2) If the .class you have is named `caos.aaai.CaosEngine` then `java` looks for `caos/aaai/CaosEngine.class` (ie, two directories down) in each directory or JAR added to the class path.

It is often simpler to packages all classes in a JAR, with the MANIFEST.MF file of the JAR having an `Main-Class: classname` entry pointing to the `main()` class, and then start the app using `java -jar {the_jar}`

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I only have `CaosEngine.java` in `caos/aaai` I never did a JAR nor a MANIFEST.MF I only took the code from the last link I provided and try to modify it on my own to run my own class

Comment: Then you have to compile the java to get a `.class` from a `.java`. You use the Java compiler (`javac` command) or use an IDE. A JAR is mostly a ZIP file, the command to create JARs is `jar` (or ask the IDE to generate it). But this is StackExchange territory (or Java 101...).